# How Can i create master page in joomla?

Tags: joomla3.2

how I can make master page in Joomla, I need that to be same in all the pages and the content part has to change it

Answer (score 1):

I think master page of your wish would be the **index.php** page of your **template**.

Add your **theme template** by adding required joomla configuration, upload that **template** and make it as **default site template**.

You are ready to use it's **index.php** as your **master page**.
Add you can add your **dynamic content** in the same page.

I wish this will be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but i have designed the whole website and if i click on one link whole page is refreshing i want to stop that and only the content section need to be changed

Comment: In every joomla website or in any other website(PHP), page will get refreshed if you are rendering to different URL's.
But due to the cache management of joomla the links would not get much time next time.
And to use Ajax to get content without loading the whole page is not the way you can use with joomla on each new URL.